# How to render flexdashboard from the command line?

Tags: r, rstudio, flexdashboard

I have a flexdashboard Rmd that renders correctly when i press the Knit button in RStudio. I would like to render it from the command line but the naviagation bar does change when I use the command `render("myfile.rmd", flex_dashboard())`

The heading of my Rmd file is the following:

```
---
title: "Flexdashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
      theme: cosmo
      navbar:
      - { title: "Draft-For Internal Use Only", align: right }
      source_code: embed
---
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can call render with no arguments and it will pick up all of the options in YAML:

```
render("myfile.Rmd")
```

Altons was correct that using flex_dashboard() creates a new format that uses all the defaults. To render a format and keep the settings from YAML you use:

```
render("myfile.Rmd", "flex_dashboard")
```

But this latter form is only required if flex_dashboard isn't already the default format within the Rmd.

Answer (score 4):

pass arguments within the `flex_dashboard()`.

For example:

```
render("myfile.rmd", flex_dashboard(theme=simplex),output='myfile_html')
```

Comment: I saw that I can pass arguments to `flex_dashboard ` but since these are defined in the YAML of the file; is there a way to read them directly?

Comment: I presume title and author are picked up correclty? I had similar issue, it seems like render only picks the 1st level of YAML header and omit the rest - maybe a bug? I added them to render and also left them in the .Rmd in case I need to run the knit button. it works fine

Comment: Giving it more thoughts maybe the `flex_dashboard()` from render overwrites the YAML options.... just a thought

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, and to prevent people from saying, wait, what's `render`? Why can't I use `knit`?.... o ok, so why can't I then use `knit2html`? These are the steps to render a flexdashboard from the command line:

1. [Install Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/installing.html)
2. Close your current `cmd` if you haven't already.
3. Run this command: `"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin\x64\R.exe" -e "rmarkdown::render('C:/FULLPATH/myFlexDashboard.Rmd')"`
4. If it works, put that in a `.bat` file and celebrate!

(for step 3, note the slashes/backslashes... they should be exactly like that, but your R version might be different)