# How to run flexdashboard from a desktop icon

Tags: r

I am using windows 10

I have a flexdashboard .Rmd file. In an ideal world I just want to open it up from an icon on the desktop. How can I do this? Do I have to run a bat file to open R and then the file as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830791/how-to-render-flexdashboard-from-the-command-line)? Is this the only way?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a small C# application through [R.NET](http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/) that would exectute the code.

Comment: OK so I guess running a bat file is easier, and probably is the only way to run this from an icon