# Launch R Flexdashboard command line bat file

Tags: batch-file, shiny, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

i am new to flexbdashboard as well as bat files. I would like to get some help on how do i launch my flexdashboard with shiny run time using .bat file.

After reading on this post [How to render flexdashboard from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830791/how-to-render-flexdashboard-from-the-command-line) , i have tried to write my bat file

I have written some codes and save it as a .bat file. The problem is it is able to work on my home's PC while it has problems when i replicate the exact same code (i changed the file path to match my work) on my work PC.

Here is my bat file code :

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1\bin\R.exe" -e "rmarkdown::run('C:/Users/Sam/Desktop/My_Dashboard.Rmd', shiny_args = list(launch.browser = TRUE))"
```

The error i am getting is :

> Fatal error: option '-e' requires a non-empty argument.

Anyone has any idea ?

My whole idea of doing this is that i have created a dashboard in my shared network folder. So my colleague is able to access the shared network folder and double click the bat file and launch the dashboard in the browser

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does your colleague have sufficient access/privileges to run a `.Rmd` file on your personal Desktop. Have you tried placing that file in a location which you both have sufficient access to?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Apologies if i didnt clarify clearly. I am currently not able to run on my own work PC.